# Call a payable contract's function from another contract via an interface

Tags: solidity, web3js, contract-development, contract-design, remix

I have two contracts, they are connected via an interface.

When user calls `contract1` function, it uses an interface to call `contract2` function which updates it's storage.

My problem is that I can get a return value from an event, but data is not saved in that `contract2` storage.

I get such an error:

> Transaction was not mined within 50 blocks, please make sure your
>   transaction was properly sent. Be aware that it might still be mined!

here is a contract1 function which that user calls i.e. `buy()`:

```
event itemBought(uint256 itemId);

Contract2Interface private contract2Interface;

constructor() public {
    contract2Interface = Contract2Interface('contract address');
}

function buy(uint256 itemId) public payable {
      // require(some condition);

    uint256 itemId = contract2Interface.buy(itemId, msg.sender);
    emit itemBought(itemId);
}
```

here is an interface:

```
contract contract2Interface {
    function buy(uint256 itemId, address owner) public returns(uint256);
}
```

here is contract2 function:

```
mapping(bytes32 => uint256) private storage;

function encodeFunc(uint256 itemId, address owner) private pure returns(bytes32) {
    return keccak256(abi.encodePacked(itemId, owner));
}

function buy(uint256 itemId, address owner) public returns(uint256) {
    storage[encodeFunc(itemId, owner)]++;
    return itemId;
}
```

So here I get that itemId from event, but data is not saved in storage, I don't get any errors either.

what do you think a problem is ?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Your contract seems fine. I think you should choose a different name for mapping here:

```
mapping(bytes32 => uint256) private storage;
```

As `storage` is a keyword in Solidity. Also try running your contracts in REMIX, it can save you from these kind of mistakes.

Comment: Thank you for your reply! But I just renamed that variable from my long camel case one to just that simple 'storage'. Sorry for my misleading you. 

regarding Remix: I compiled and deployed my contracts using it.

and today I could catch such an error: 
> Transaction was not mined within 50 blocks, please make sure your transaction was properly sent. Be aware that it might still be mined!

Comment: I have tried increasing my gas limit and now it works pretty fine, but data is not saved anyway. If I call contract2 function which updates it's state then I should see those transactions, right ?

Comment: still couldn't resolve that issue, is there any problem there except that variable name ?

Answer (score 0):

For what it is worth you could make contract2interface immutable since it's just used in the constructor.

Answer (score -1):

I think the way that you stored your data is wrong, i'm not sure but it seems you trying to get the data that's not stored.

Comment: This answer doesn't add anything to the question asked.